# How to format worksheet as rows and columns expand on Excel for Mac ver. 16.24

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm using Excel version 16.24 for Mac, and I did some recording of Macros to format the worksheets followed by a loop to all the other worksheets.

However, there are 2 issues I am facing at the moment.

Issue 1: If an imported sheet is blank, there will be an error as I do not know how to create a skip to the next sheet. I have to remember to delete the sheet for the code to run without errors.

Issue 2: As I run the "FormatAllSheets" code, it only expands to a restricted area as it's recorded with data I have. In the case of the following month's data, it will not format it as there is a limitation. from the recording.

Below is the code I am using currently recorded step-by-step based on only existing data, I need to have it useable for future data as well.

```
Sub FormatSheet()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Font.Size = 14
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Range("A2").Select
End Sub
Sub FormatAllSheets()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    Do While i <= Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Select 
        FormatSheet 
        i = i + 1 
        Loop
End Sub
```

The above work as expected but I need to improve it to make it more seamless and responsive.

All help will be very much appreciated. I'm still new to this so pardon me for asking too many silly questions. Thank you.

Comment: For issue 1, put a formula to check for text and numbers in cell A1, then as part of your loop check that cell, if true continue, if false skip to next sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue needs a check to see if any data in cell and then skip if not.
Your second issue you need to find the last used column and then you can use the range and the column number to format. Note there is no need to use selection or select as it's slows down performance. I think it will be best to use `.UsedRange` and just format only the cells that actually have data.

```
 Sub FormatSheet()
    Dim lrow as long
    Dim ws as ActiveSheet

    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
    End With

    With Range("A" & lrow).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Font.Size = 14
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
End Sub

    Sub FormatAllSheets()
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 2
        Do While i <= Worksheets.Count
            Worksheets(i).Select
            if Len(Trim(.Range("A1").value)) > 0 then '->change range where data is
               FormatSheet 
               i = i + 1
            else
               i = i + 1
            Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @QuickSilver, pardon for the noob question but is there something I need to define or change in this line? if Len(Trim(.Range("A1").value)) > 0 then '->change range where data is

Comment: Hi @TimothyWong Exactly I assumed you had data in A1 but you need to change it to a cell that makes sense to you and you would expect to always have data. No need to apologise this is a learning process.

Comment: Hi @QuickSilver, thank you for the explanation. I will test it out!

Comment: @TimothyWong please remember to accept the answer if this helped you.